# Fine Uploader, getting rid of default behavior on "failed upload"

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am using fine uploader to upload files to the Server but got an issue.

file gets uploaded to the Server perfectly fine but Server returns the response without **{ success : true }** message, so, by default, fine Uploader  treats it as failed upload and shows me error.
Is there a way to avoid this behavior?
How can I make fine uploader treat every response as a successful response even if the response does not have **{ "success": true }**

here is my fine uploader code

`this.manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
                template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
                request: {
                    endpoint: 'some end point'
                },
                thumbnails: {
                    placeholders: {
                        waitingPath: '../scripts/plugins/fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                        notAvailablePath: '../scripts/plugins/fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                    }
                },
                autoUpload: true,
                debug: false,
                callbacks: {
                    onComplete: function (event, id, xhr) {

                        ** will call some functions here **

                    },
                    onError: function (id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
                        try {
                            if(xhr.status == 204 && xhr.responseText.length == 0){
                                response = qq.parseJson('{"success": true}');
                            }
                            else{
                                response = qq.parseJson(xhr.responseText);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (exception){
                        }
                    }
                },
                failedUploadTextDisplay: {
                    mode: 'custom',
                    maxChars: 20,
                    responseProperty: 'error',
                    enableTooltip: true
                }
            });`

Comment: https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1325

Comment: I already went through it but solution is not clear there.

Comment: there is no solution, until 6.0 is released